# How to show that every group in the normal series of $G$ is normal in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

For a group $G$ we define $Z_1(G) = Z(G)$ and then

$$Z_{i+1}(G) = \pi^{-1}(Z(G/Z_i(G)))$$

with that we can build a normal series

$$\{1\} \triangleleft Z_1(G) \triangleleft\cdots \triangleleft Z_n(G) \triangleleft \cdots $$

and I am asked to prove that $Z_i(G) \triangleleft G\ \forall i$.

I thought this would be done by induction and so I started by stating that for $i = 1$ it comes directly by definition.

Then I proceeded to show that $Z_i(G) \triangleleft G \implies Z_{i+1}(G) \triangleleft G$:

First note that $z \in Z_{i+1}(G) \iff \pi(z) \in Z(G/Z_i(G))$ that is, $\pi(z)$ commutes with every element in $G/Z_i(G)$. Having said that, let $z \in Z_{i+1}(G), g \in G$:

$$\pi(gzg^{-1}) = \pi(g)\pi(z)\pi(g)^{-1} = \pi(z)\pi(g)\pi(g)^{-1} = \pi(z)$$

because $\pi(z)$ commutes with every element; if $\pi(gzg^{-1}) = \pi(z)$ then $\pi(gzg^{-1})$ also commutes with every element, hence $gzg^{-1} \in Z_{i+1}(G)$ and so $Z_{i+1}(G) \triangleleft G$.

It feels as if I didn't use the induction hypothesis, but my proof also seems correct, so is it the case where a direct proof was possible? i.e. I could prove $Z_i(G) \triangleleft G$ directly for all $i$? Or did I use the induction hypothesis without even realizing?

Comment: You don't have to use any induction at all. These subgroups are called $i$-th centers of $G$ and they are characteristic subgroups of $G$.

Comment: @Levent alright, I didn't know what to call them. When you say I don't need induction, you mean my calculations are right or you mean there is a proof without induction but mine is incorrect?

Comment: Your calculations are correct and does not use induction at all.

Comment: Okay, I was clearly wrong since you use the fact that $Z_i(G)$ is normal to build $G/Z_i(G)$. Hence you in fact use the induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used that $Z_i(G)$ is normal when you wrote $G/Z_i(G)$. Other than that, this result is true for any normal subgroup i.e., if $N$ is normal in $G$ then $H=\pi^{-1}(Z(G/N))$ is also normal in $G$.

Comment: and I suppose a similar proof would work; thanks